# placing words corresponding to a key in a singe row

Tags: text-processing, awk, python

I have a symbol table of the form (key-value pairs)

```
01  aaluu desii
01  aaluu cipsa 
01  amaruuda ilaahabaadii
02  hai
02  nahii
02  txamaatxara
```

To start with, I am supposed to place words(corresponding to the same key) in  the same line.

The expected output is

```
01 aaluu desii aaluu cipsa amaruuda ilaahabaadii
02 hai nahii txamaatxara
```

Note that there is a TAB that separates the key from the value in the input file as well as the output file.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '
    :1                                  #just mark
    N                                   #append next line
    s/^\(\([0-9]\+\s\+\).*\)\n\2/\1 /   #compare nums in the line beginning
    t1                                  #if prev succeed return to mark
    P                                   #print before \newline
    D                                   #delete before \newline, go to start
' <(sort -k1n table.file)
```

Comment: So how does _this_ one work...? (Please.)

Comment: @roaima see commented

Answer (score 1):

with awk:

```
 awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {a[$1]=a[$1]" "$i}} END{for ( i in a){print i"\t"a[i]}}'
```

An array `a` with index `$1`(key) is created and the all fields in a line except first field is appended to this array. This wil be done for all the lines that has similar key.

At the `END` iterate thorugh the array `a` index and print array index (keys) as well as content of the array(values) with tab seperator between key and values.

Comment: Updated the answer with explanation. I hope this is can help.